# Phonological Differences Between Given Names and Surnames

Tags: phonology, names

I'm writing a CRF parser that [splits a name string into components](https://github.com/datamade/name-parser). For example,

```
Bob Belcher => <GivenName>Bob</GivenName> <Surname>Belcher</Surname>
Belcher, Bob => <Surname>Belcher,</Surname> <GivenName>Bob</GivenName>
```

I'm looking for research on typical phonological differences between given names and surnames, particularly in the United States. Something like the results on [phonological differences between male, female, and unisex first names](http://www.swarthmore.edu/SocSci/Linguistics/Papers/2007/fredrickson_annie.pdf).

I already know about [surname affixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_family_name_affixes).

Comment: Considering that [Reagan and Kennedy are now popular girls names and Lincoln and Jackson are popular boys names](http://www.babycenter.com/top-baby-names-2013) I don't think this is going to be very productive...

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking for hard rules but research on tendencies.

Comment: Could you provide guidance on how to make the question more specific?